# Could not store streamed data in a file using Python

Tags: python, csv, stream

I want to store the data in `csv` or `excelsheet` type of format. I am currently receiving the data at my serial port. But, I want to store few bytes from continuous stream bytes into my `csv` file. Below is my code I am working. I am new at python programming so I would appreciate your inputs.

```
import struct,serial,csv
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)
print("Connected to: " + ser.portstr)
ser.isOpen()
ser.write("\x7E\x00\x0F\x10\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFE\x00\x00\x61\x92") #Send command to distant node
while 1:
    read_val = ser.read(300)
    str1=list(read_val)
    str2= #String value that match the address of node
    ''' Do some math to achieve parametric result from 'read_val'''

def csv_write():
    with open(tst.csv, "wb") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for line in data:
        writer.writerow(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    csv_writer()
    data = <list format result from math calculations,which is done on 'read_val'>
```

Although I am receiving continuous data but when I am unable to make `csv` file from calculated readings.